# How to properly link to libraries in CMake (using Boehm GC)?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, static-libraries

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but can't seem to get it working. I've already checked a bunch of posts.

I have a static library libRuntime.a, generated like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Runtime)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(Runtime library.cpp)
find_library(GC gc)
message(${GC})
target_link_libraries(Runtime PUBLIC ${GC})
```

library.cpp uses Boehm GC, which is why I'm also linking it with my `Runtime` target.

Now, I want to call functions from my libRuntime.a, so I have the following other CMake project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
find_library(TESTLIB Runtime lib)
message(${TESTLIB})
target_link_libraries(test ${TESTLIB})
```

I have pasted library.h into the project, and also pasted libRuntime.a into a directory called `lib`, so the definitions are known and the library is found. Calling functions from my Runtime library now gives me:

```
/path.../Scheme-Compiler/Runtime/library.cpp:12: undefined reference to `GC_init'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libRuntime.a(library.cpp.o): in function `alloc_atom':
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use a **separate** CMake invocation to create the executable, the properties of the `Runtime` CMake target from your first project are not known. Specifically, CMake will not know any of the `Runtime` library's dependencies (i.e. `GC`), so you have to list them explicitly when linking `Runtime` to your executable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
find_library(TESTLIB Runtime lib)
message(${TESTLIB})

# Find GC library.
find_library(GC gc)
# Link GC here, along with the Runtime library.
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${GC} ${TESTLIB})
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I thought I added gc to my Runtime. Didn't it work because it is a shared library, or why?

Comment: @TimEichholz `libRuntime.a` is a static library. You can't link anything to a [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info).
It is just an archive of object files. No linkage is involved in its production. Even if it was shared library, it's dependency on `libgc` would still become a dependency of your executable.

Comment: @TimEichholz Mike's comment is correct; you still need to explicitly link the GC library. However, if you merge these two CMake projects into one, CMake would track the dependencies of the `Runtime` library **for you**, so you would *only* need to mention the `Runtime` target when calling `target_link_libraries()` for your executable.